# Capybara not finding submit button by name

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I have some weirdness occurring while trying to switch from webrat to capybara.  The error is this:

```
And I press "Create floob"
    # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:27
    no button with value or id or text 'Create floob' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

The html in my app looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="buttons">
  <ol>
    <input id="floob_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create floob" /> 
  </ol>
</fieldset>
```

I would have thought that capybara would look at the `value` of the buttons on the page, and reading the documentation this does seem to be the case, but it's not working!  If I change the line in my cuke file to `And I press "floob_submit"` everything works, but I'd rather not change all my features...

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this might be happening and if there's a fix?  Thanks friends!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see is that you aren't wrapping your input in an `<li></li>`.  This might be confusing enough for the DOM to cause your problem.